# Grant admin access for some machines on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to grant full admin access to some users on some machines. I know two ways to achieve this

1. Login to each machine and add them in its Administrators group
2. Make them domain admin but this would make them admin for whole domain

How can I do it from Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

It wll be Gpo.

Local users and groups > target computers where you need need.
[image]